# Iterating list of dictionaries with dictionary

Tags: ansible

I'm having trouble grasping data manipulation in Ansible. Here's the setup:

```yaml
- hosts: emirr01
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    setup:
      - emirr01: { label: "label1" }
      - emirr02: { label: "label2" }
      - emirr03: { label: "label3" }
    lookup: [ "emirr01", "emirr02"]
    use_labels: [ ]
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="setup={{ setup }}"
    - debug: msg="lookup={{ lookup }}"

    - debug: msg="item0={{ item.0 }} item1={{ item.1 }}"
      when: inventory_hostname == item.1
      with_nested:
        - "{{ setup }}"
        - "{{ lookup }}"

    - set_fact:
        use_labels: "{{ use_labels + [ item.1.label ] }}"
      when: item.0 == item.1.label
      with_nested:
        - "{{ setup }}"
        - "{{ lookup }}"

    - debug: msg="use_labels={{ use_labels }}"
```

What I need is to set a fact `use_labels` which is a list of labels as defined in `setup` list for each host found in `lookup` list. What I expect is a list like this:

```yaml
[ "label1", "label2" ]
```

My problem is not being able to "reach" label in a list I get in item.1 which is (example):

```yaml
item1=[{'emirr02': {'label': 'label2'}}
```

Here's is the error:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml -l emirr01

PLAY [emirr01] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [emirr01] =>
  msg: 'setup=[{''emirr01'': {''label'': ''label1''}}, {''emirr02'': {''label'': ''label2''}}, {''emirr03'': {''label'': ''label3''}}]'

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [emirr01] =>
  msg: lookup=['emirr01', 'emirr02']

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [emirr01] => (item=[{'emirr01': {'label': 'label1'}}, 'emirr01']) =>
  msg: 'item0={''emirr01'': {''label'': ''label1''}} item1=emirr01'
skipping: [emirr01] => (item=[{'emirr01': {'label': 'label1'}}, 'emirr02'])
ok: [emirr01] => (item=[{'emirr02': {'label': 'label2'}}, 'emirr01']) =>
  msg: 'item0={''emirr02'': {''label'': ''label2''}} item1=emirr01'
skipping: [emirr01] => (item=[{'emirr02': {'label': 'label2'}}, 'emirr02'])
ok: [emirr01] => (item=[{'emirr03': {'label': 'label3'}}, 'emirr01']) =>
  msg: 'item0={''emirr03'': {''label'': ''label3''}} item1=emirr01'
skipping: [emirr01] => (item=[{'emirr03': {'label': 'label3'}}, 'emirr02'])

TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [emirr01]: FAILED! =>
  msg: |-
    The conditional check 'item.0 == item.1.label' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item.0 == item.1.label): 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'label'

    The error appears to be in '/home/ansible/test.yml': line 21, column 7, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

    The offending line appears to be:


        - set_fact:
          ^ here
```

It all boils down to "digging" for a value from a dictionary in a list. Does anyone have an idea of how to reach `item.1.label`? It's a little bit frustrating since this is trivial in Python or other programming languages but in Ansible... Or maybe my mistake is to use a wrong kind of `with_*` loop for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Q: **"*Expect a list like this [label1, label2]*"**

```yaml
    setup:
      - emirr01: { label: "label1" }
      - emirr02: { label: "label2" }
      - emirr03: { label: "label3" }
    lookup: [ "emirr01", "emirr02"]
```

A: This is a typical example of a wrong data structure for this use-case. A list of dictionaries can't be used in [*mapping*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) the filter *extract*. Moreover, the keys in the dictionaries don't have to be unique, because they are hidden in the items of the list. The solution is simple with the data in the dictionary

```yaml
    setup:
      emirr01: { label: "label1" }
      emirr02: { label: "label2" }
      emirr03: { label: "label3" }
```

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        use_labels: "{{ lookup|map('extract', setup, 'label')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  use_labels:
  - label1
  - label2
```

---

One of the options is creating a dictionary from the list first. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        setup2: "{{ setup2|default({})|combine(item) }}"
      loop: "{{ setup }}"
```

Then the dictionary *setup2* can be used to get the same result

---

It's possible to filter the list directly. For example, the task below gives the same result too

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        use_labels: "{{ setup|map('dict2items')|map('first')|
                        selectattr('key', 'in', lookup )|
                        map(attribute='value.label')|
                        list }}"
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, thanks for pointing out that with those dashes missing I get a dictionary of dictionaries `msg: 'setup={''emirr01'': {''label'': ''label1''}, ''emirr02'': {''label'': ''label2''}, ''emirr03'': {''label'': ''label3''}}'` which is way easier to manage and is the actual data stucture I wanted to use in the first place. You live, you learn...

Answer (score 1):

Your issue with the `with_nested` is actually coming from how those "two-lists" loops are working.

When you are using loops like `with_nested`, the `item.0` is the item of the first list, while the `item.1` is the item of the second list.

Because `lookup` is a list and not a list of dictionaries like

```yaml
lookup:
  - label: "emirr01"
  - label: "emirr02"
```

You can use the value of `item.1` right away.

So the way to have you issue fixed is to use it this way:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    use_labels: "{{ use_labels + [ item.0[item.1].label ] }}"
  when: item.0[item.1].label is defined
  with_nested:
    - "{{ setup }}"
    - "{{ lookup }}"
```

---

Here is a playbook demonstrating this:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:  
    - set_fact:
        use_labels: "{{ use_labels | default([]) + [ item.0[item.1].label ] }}"
      when: item.0[item.1].label is defined
      with_nested:
        - "{{ setup }}"
        - "{{ lookup }}"
      vars:
        setup:
          - emirr01: 
              label: "label1"
          - emirr02: 
              label: "label2"
          - emirr03: 
              label: "label3"
        lookup: 
          - "emirr01"
          - "emirr02"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ use_labels }}"
```

Wich gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'emirr01': {'label': 'label1'}}, 'emirr01'])
skipping: [localhost] => (item=[{'emirr01': {'label': 'label1'}}, 'emirr02']) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=[{'emirr02': {'label': 'label2'}}, 'emirr01']) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'emirr02': {'label': 'label2'}}, 'emirr02'])
skipping: [localhost] => (item=[{'emirr03': {'label': 'label3'}}, 'emirr01']) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=[{'emirr03': {'label': 'label3'}}, 'emirr02']) 

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "label1",
        "label2"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Interestingly, this worked for me:

`- set_fact: use_labels: "{{ use_labels + [ item.0[item.1].label ] if item.0[item.1].label is defined else omit }}"`

Got: 

`ok: [emirr01] => msg: use_labels=['label1', 'label2']`

Comment: Well the `if item.0[item.1].label is defined else omit` is needless, as `when: item.0[item.1].label is defined` will exclude this possibility

Comment: I'd think so too but when I skip `... if ... else omit` I get (Ansible 2.9): `Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ use_labels + [ item.0[item.1].label ] }}): can only concatenate str (not "list") to str'`

Comment: I've learned that this kind of error happens when the value you add to the list does not yeld any result.

Comment: For example, when I do this: `use_labels: "{{ use_labels + [ item.0[item.1].label|default([]) ] }}"` I'm getting this result: `msg: use_labels=['label1', [], [], 'label2', [], []]`.

Comment: Ok, got you. You  are actually kind of doing the same in an `omit` that the `when` would be doing. There is off course different flavours of doing the same thing. To be honest, I like the `when` better because it yields a skipped in the recap when your will yield an OK, but add nothing to the list. But that's just a matter of taste.

Comment: Yep, but the fascinating part is that there IS `where` clause in the loop when the empty results are yelded. So go figure, I'm not 100% sure why it is so, but the cool thing is that it works, one way or another. Thank you kindly for your help!